# Remove all traces of wordpress while using wordpress "plugin"

Tags: php, wordpress

I just purchased cornerstone page builder which is a drag and drop website builder. The problem I have right now is that it works as a wordpress plugin making me access it through the wordpress admin panel.

Is there a way for me to remove everything "wordpress related" to basically hide everything that has to do with wordpress and just let me access the plugin without signing in to wordpress, maybe using my own log in function?

Comment: Hi there. This is a very intriguing situation. In fact there isn't any out of the box solution that would allow you to do that without accessing the WordPress admin panel. However, you could achieve that partially by trying a few different solutions together. First, I'd check if the plugin has any settings for user roles, if it has, then you could define it to be managed by a certain type of user role that has very few capabilities, such as the Editor user role. It'd be better to register a new type of user role, e.g http://managewp.com/create-custom-user-roles-wordpress

Comment: After setting a new type of user role, make it so that it has at least the same capabilities as the Editor user role, e.g: https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Editor - This would allow user created under the new custom user role to be able to perform actions such as create, delete and publish posts/pages etc. You'd end up with a cleaner WordPress admin, while having full access to the cornerstone plugin and the mandatory capabilities for managing posts and pages.

Comment: In order to make it easy, you could try to achieve the above by creating an Editor user and then settings this specific user role as allowed to manage the cornerstone page builder in case it has any settings for that.  Later on, you could user a white label plugin to totally customize wordpress with colors, logo, remove specific elements that resembles WordPress itself as the default login page, the login url, etc. With the help of other plugins you're able to remove almost everything WordPress from the view of the end user.

Comment: There are some plugins that go even further when it comes to hide the fact you use WordPress, e.g: you can change the WP default uploads directory, rename or change the default wp-content directory and so on.

Comment: @AdrianoMonecchi Thank you, I'll try this out when I get back after my Christmas holidays. Sounds like a good approach! Merry Christmas to you :)